Captcha NOT showing in a Power Page Run Time But Shows At Design Time
I am creating a new Power Pages site and adding a form to the page. I am enabling the Captcha for Anonymous & Authenticated users and it is showing at design time but not at run time. The form is showing as expected without the captcha. I am using a development environment. Any help is highly appreciated.
